# Add unicode char to a standard font (consolas)

Tags: linux, unicode, fonts

I'm using a lot the terminal (that support UTF-8) to display information like ascii tables, menus, etc.

I strongly argue that using the proper unicode symbols to draw a table offer a much better readability than only playing with standard ASCII symbols.

In 2015 (even if small villages of indomitable old timers still holds out against C99), I think that I can ask my people to install a specific terminal font to use my tools and scripts. Of course I can still imagine implementing a compatibility mode where I only use creepy ascii chars.

So, we are currently using `Powerline Consolas` as some of us use vim with vim-airline. With this font I can already display pretty tables like this:

```
┌──────────────────────────────────┐
|               Data               |
├───────┬───────┬────────┬──────┬──┤
│ Name  │ Alias │ Depths │ Type │# │
├───────┼───────┼────────┼──────┼──┤
│ foo   │       │   2    │ int  │1 │
│ bar   │ babar │   1    │ long │2 │
└───────┴───────┴────────┴──────┴──┘
```

However, to push my argument a step further. I would like to use more custom chars i.e. symbols and logos to the font we are using.

My question is:

What tool can I use to easily edit my font i.e. TrueType to add new Unicode chars?

I found nice online tools like [fontastic](http://fontastic.me/), but I still did not find anything that can take in input an existing font.

Comment: "I think that I can ask my people to install a specific terminal font to use my tools and scripts". You are mistaken. Won't happen.

Comment: @n.m. Well, I'm sure it will happen :) Our team is only 5-10 people that do not know much about linux. They don't even know what Unicode is. However, they can easily use the tools I provide.

Comment: So the question is not about tools used primarily by programmers (no programmers that don't know about Unicode are allowed to exist in 2015). "How to modify a True Type font" is a general question about software, not a programming question.

Comment: You're right but your opinion as programmer is very interesting because you could identify in my question a x-y problem and offer a better solution

Comment: Most terminals offer pseudographic capabilites out of the box (but not your custom symbols obviously). The easiest way to work with them is ncurses. Search for "ncurses line drawing".